# Error installing new theme in opencart 2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am new to opencart and I am using opencart version 2.3.0.2 and working on xampp localhost.

I tried to install new theme (simplica free theme) by copying the theme files(catalog, system ) to my project folder which already have those 4 folders(admin,catalog,image,system). So it merges with those 2 folders.

When I go back to my backend extensions>extensions and select modules, I can't see any new module. Under extension>extension>themes, I can only see my default theme. also under system>setting>mystore, I can only see default store theme under theme option.

Did I do anything wrong? or what should I do to install a new theme?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, hope this may help someone with similar problem.

I had to go to extensions>extensions then select themes then had click edit button of the default store theme. Under general> theme directory, I was able to select my theme.

Comment: this helped me a lot ! Thanks!